# wordpress child theme loads child style twice, no parent style

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

The WP codex has me twisted in knots with all its self-contradictions and misinformation around creating a child theme. The child theme page says I only need style.css and functions.php. That's wrong. The parent theme is twentyfifteen. I tried the recommended pattern and then followed the resulting PHP errors and added all the files noted in the complaints. My child theme, twentyfifteen-child, now contains:  footer.php, functions.php, header.php, index.php, sidebar.php and style.css.

The child style.css file contains only the stylesheet header:

```
Theme Name: Twenty Fifteen Child
Theme URI: http://dwp.avionicsspecialists.net/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twenty-fifteen-child/
```

Because the codex is contradictory I tried variations on the Theme URI folder:  twenty-fifteen-child, twentyfifteen-child and twentyfifteen. None of the variations affected the outcome.

The functions.php file contains the following enqueing code.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    $parent_style = 'parent-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style )
    );
}
```

The other files I copied directly from the parent twentyfifteen theme without any changes.

When I activate the child theme it displays a WP site with no styling at all.  It loads the child style sheet twice and not the parent style sheet. The Codex says get_template_directory_uri() always returns the parent theme path. Not true. In my theme it returns the child theme path. In the db, where wp_options.option_name = 'template' the value is 'twentyfifteen-child'.

If I manually change that value to 'twentyfifteen' I get results closer to what I need. That case loads both the parent and child style sheets. However, manually altering the database is not a valid solution.

I'm out of ideas for variants. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the header of `style.css` theme is a CSS comment (it should start with `/*` and end with `*/`) and it has this line:

```
/* 
Template:     twentyfifteen
*/
```

Rule of thumb in programming:

> *Don't delete code you do not fully understand. Sooner or later it will hit the fan*.

More details on child themes and their headers [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet).

> ***The comment header lines in* `style.css` *are required for WordPress to be able to identify the Theme*** and display it in the Administration Panel under Design > Themes as an available Theme option along with any other installed Themes.

Comment: I was missing the Template line. My example did not show the comment tags - it simply showed the lines that I edited from the Codex child theme page sample code [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). That Codex page could be much more clear about the steps needed to successfully make a child theme.

Comment: To succesfully create a child theme that works, all one needs is `/* Template: parent-theme-folder-name */` at the start of its `style.css`, but it's not recommended. Depending on parent theme, the parent stylesheet might or might not load. It loads automatically for `twentyfifteen`, so I didn't over-complicate my answer :).

Answer (score 1):

The only item required to create a child theme within wordpress is this information within `style.css`:

```
   /*
   * Theme Name: Your Child Theme Name
   * Author: Who you are
   * Version: 1.0
   * Template: twentyfifteen
   */
```

You do not need include the URI function within `functions.php`.

Comment: Samantha, your statement is not quite correct. Please run a child theme with only this one-liner as header: 
`/* Template: twentyfifteen */`

Comment: Thanks @samantha-ingram, your answer did help. I also found that the function theme_enqueue_styles() was indeed necessary in the child functions.php file to make my site work properly.